# Javascript function using lodash forEach returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, return, lodash

I'm writing a ReactJS app and I have a for loop in a function `filterSelected` which goes through an array of region names (eg.`["Thailand", "Malaysia"]`) and should return an array of their corresponding region codes (eg.`["TH", "MY"]`).

In my `mapRegionToCode` function it goes through an object of objects to make this mapping, and the console log correctly prints the corresponding region code, however the function is returning `undefined`.

Any ideas why would be much appreciated!

```
mapRegionToCode(region) { // region = "Thailand"
  _.forEach(_.values(this.props.regionsCodes), regionCode => {
    if(regionCode.country.countryName === region) {
      console.log(regionCode.country.countryCode); //"TH"
      return regionCode.country.countryCode;
    }
  });
}

filterSelected(filters) {
...
  for(let i = 0; i < regionsArray.length; i++){
    const regionCode = this.mapRegionToCode(regionName);
    console.log(regionCode); //undefined
    regionNames.push(regionCode);
  }
...
}
```

Comment: I think you meant [_.map](https://lodash.com/docs/#map) not `forEach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I read what you wanted to do wrong. What you need to do is the following:

1. Find the regionCode with `country.countryName === region`
2. Return its `country.countryCode`

With lodash, you can do the following:

```
mapRegionToCode(region) {
  return _.find(_.values(this.props.regionsCodes),regionCode => regionCode.country.countryName === region).country.countryCode
}
```

**Original Answer**

You forgot to add a `return` in your `mapRegionToCode` function:

```
mapRegionToCode(region) { // region = "Thailand"
  return _.map(_.values(this.props.regionsCodes), regionCode => {
    if(regionCode.country.countryName === region) {
      console.log(regionCode.country.countryCode); //"TH"
      return regionCode.country.countryCode;
    }
  });
}
```

(Also, you need to use `_.map` instead of `_.forEach`)

Comment: This causes `mapRegionToCode("Thailand")` to return an array of size 243 instead of `"TH"`

Comment: This works thanks! Still not sure why my code wasn't working though, I had a return

Comment: You used a `return` in the function you passed to _.map. Which means it returned for this function, not the mapRegionToCode function.